# Why was the moodbar package omitted from 16.04 LTS?

Tags: packaging

The [moodbar](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/moodbar) package has been available since [at least 12.04 LTS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=moodbar&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) but has now disappeared:

```
$ grep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
$ sudo apt install moodbar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package moodbar is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'moodbar' has no installation candidate
```

What happened, and why?

Comment: Have you tried enabling canonical partner repository?

Comment: No. From `curl http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/partner/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | zgrep moodbar` I expect that it's not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to its [publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/moodbar), its removal was [requested](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=803203) by the Debian Quality Assurance Team, which provided these two reasons:

> It's orphaned and dead upstream (the release in the archive was released in 2007). It depends on Gstreamer 0.10, which is scheduled for removal from the archive.

In a [related request](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785897#23) it was suggested that Exaile be removed temporarily until it has been updated to use newer software libraries.

Since the latest development version of Exaile appears to have been [successfully](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785897#33) updated and still [requires](https://github.com/exaile/exaile/blob/2488d138dceb1822c78f3ad6eaa3a6cb9ff588fc/plugins/moodbar/generator.py#L82) an external `moodbar` command, I expect that a moodbar package will accompany Exaile's return.

Answer (score 2):

Ypu can download it from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/moodbar/0.1.2-6).

Not sure thought why it was removed (it is marked as "deleted" there), so pay attention when installing it (it might break something else).